# Unable to add product to favorite screen and getting this TypeError: undefined is not a function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-context

I can't add the product to favorite page and get the above error.

I'm using React-Native with context hook to add the product to cart and favorite pages. The problem is all actions in reducer hook are working except add to favorite action is not working.

Context Code

```js
const initialState = {
  products: ProductData, // productData is dummy data where i place all products with details
  cart: [],
  FavoritesList: [],
};
 
const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'ADD_PRODUCT_TO_FAVORITE':
      const product = action.payload;
      const index = state.products.findIndex((item)=> item?.id === product?.id)
      if (index >= 0) {
        state.splice(index, 1);
      } else {
        state.push(product)
      }

      return [...state,];

    case 'CLEAR':
      return {cart :[]}
           
    default:
      throw new Error(`unknow action.${action.type}`)
  }
}
```

favorite screen code

```
const Faviroute = () => {
  const { FavoritesList } = useCart();
  
  return (
    <View
      style={{
        // flex:1,
      }}
    >
      {(FavoritesList.length === 0) ?
        <View> 
          <Text>Get your favourite Coffee easily</Text>
        </View>   
      : <View> 
          {/*Card Container*/}
          <ScrollView>
            <View>
              {FavoritesList.map((item, index) => (         
                <View key={index}>           
                  <Text>{`Product Name: ${item.name}`}</Text>           
                  <Text>{`Size: ${item.size}`}</Text>           
                  <Text>{`Quantity: ${item.qty}`}</Text>           
                  <Text>{`Price: ${item.price}`}</Text>         
                </View>       
              ))}       
            </View>
          </ScrollView>
        </View>
      }
    </View>
  )
}
```

Comment: in reducer function you are trying to push or splice directly to state instead of state.products or state.FavoritesList.

Comment: State must be immutable. To use mutable methods on state, use immer or redux-toolkit. 
Additionally, if you pass in the index of the item clicked in front, you don't have to use findIndex in the reducer. Your logic is much simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array `splice` and `push` methods mutate the existing array reference. Create shallow copies ***then*** overwrite. In this case if you would like to remove an element then filter the current state, and when adding an element concatenate. Make sure you are updating and returning the correct state properties.

Example:

```js
const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'ADD_PRODUCT_TO_FAVORITE':
      const product = action.payload;

      const index = state.FavoritesList.findIndex(
        (item)=> item?.id === product?.id
      );

      if (index !== -1) {
        return {
          ...state,
          products: state.FavoritesList.filter((_, i) => i !== index),
        };
      } else {
        return {
          ...state,
          products: state.FavoritesList.concat(product),
        };
      }

    case 'CLEAR':
      return { ...state, cart: [], FavoritesList: [] };
           
    default:
      console.log("unhandled action", { action });
      return state; // <-- just return current state
  }
};
```

### Suggestion

Instead of double-storing the product data, the "favorited" products should store *just* the product id. You can get back the complete favorites array derived from the products array filtered by products with a favorited id.

Example:

```js
const initialState = {
  products: ProductData,
  cart: [],
  favorites: {},
};

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'ADD_PRODUCT_TO_FAVORITE':
      const product = action.payload;

      return {
        ...state,
        favorites: {
          ...state.favorites,
          [product.id]: !state.favorites[product.id],
        },
      };

    case 'CLEAR':
      return { ...state, cart: [], favorites: {} };
           
    default:
      console.log("unhandled action", { action });
      return state; // <-- just return current state
  }
};
```

```js
const { favorites, products } = useCart();

const favoritesList = products.filter(product => favorites[product.id]);
```

Comment: Hey Resse, Thank you so much is your answers are helpful, but for your record the first answer is only adding one single product not multiple, but the suggestion  answer is the one I want because I can add the product only once and i can add multiple products. thanks again . really appreciate your time and your great help

Comment: @OmarBakoban Oh, sorry, I tried my best to understand what you were trying to accomplish with that code. Glad it works for you now, and happy to have helped. Cheers.

Comment: you killed bro,  please don't be sorry. I'm grateful to you

Comment: Mr. Resse, if I would to remove the product from favorite list one by one can you show please how the case delete code from favorite will be ? because i was trying to do so but it failed

Comment: @OmarBakoban It was my understanding of your code that this is effectively what the `ADD_PRODUCT_TO_FAVORITE` action is supposed to do, e.g. if a product is already favorited, then it is removed from the array, otherwise it is appended to it. It's more of a `TOGGLE_PRODUCT_TO_FAVORITE` action since it adds ***and*** removes them. Like I said, perhaps I've misunderstood your use case and what you actually wanted the code to do.

Answer (score -1):

Can you try below mentioned code.

```
   const reducer = (state = initialState, action)=>{
        switch(action.type){
           case 'ADD_PRODUCT_TO_FAVORITE':
            const product = action.payload;
            const index = state.products.findIndex((item)=> item?.id === product?.id)
            if (index >= 0){
                 state.products.splice(index, 1);
            } 
            state.FavoritesList.push(product)
            return [...state,];
    
            case 'CLEAR':
                  return {cart :[]}
               
            default:
                throw new Error(`unknow action.${action.type}`)
        }

}
```

Comment: unfortunately buddy ,I had tried this before I post it giving another terrible error between thanks for your help really appreciated